# How to avoid commenting out ruby version in Gemfile while working locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile, incompatibility

It looks like heroku is now defaulting to using ruby 2.0.0 out of the box when you upload a rails app.

One of my gems breaks due to some incompatibility issue that I don't really want to look into. The solution is of course to write `ruby '1.9.2'` or what have you in the Gemfile.

Problem is when running the server locally, `ruby()` is only recognized by heroku, not your local bundler and so I have to comment it out every time while starting a local server.

Is there a clever way around this that I am not aware of?

Comment: You bundler is out of date. Update your bundler gem and it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's [article about specifying ruby versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) say this:

> If you’re using a Bundler 1.1.4 or lower you’ll see the following
>   error:
>
> undefined method `ruby' for #
>   (NoMethodError)
>
> You’ll need to install bundler 1.2.0 or greater to use the ruby
>   keyword.

I think you just need to update your local bundler to 1.2.0 or greater, as mine (1.3.5) recognize the ruby directive just fine as well.